# How to use devise to authenticate across multiple models during sign in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have three models that I would like to incorporate into the authentication process of my rails app:

**Account**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :name,:created_at
     ...
     has_many :user_accounts
     has_many :users ,through: :user_accounts
     ...
end
```

*which contains the name of the account and its id*

**User Account**

```
class UserAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
     ...
     belongs_to :account
     belongs_to :user
     ...
end
```

*which matches a given user_id to an account_id*


and,

**User**

```
class User< ActiveRecord::Base
     ...
     attr_accessible :email, :password, ...
     ...
     has_many :user_accounts ,:dependent => :destroy
     has_many :accounts ,through: :user_accounts
     ...
end
```

Currently the sign in page has fields for an email and password, but I would like to add an additional field for "Account" which would contain the account name and check to see if the user belongs to that account. In this scenario a user can belong to many accounts and an account can have multiple users. What would be the best way to go about this (preferably without resorting to subdomains)? Thanks!

Comment: I smell `accepts_nested_attributes_for:` :)

Comment: @Pavan Do you know how I'd use this exactly? Do I simply just stick `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_accounts, :accounts` in the User model and change **devise.rb**'s authentication_keys?

Comment: Have you considered rolling your own authentication? In my experience Devise is great if you use it out of the box but once you mess with the default data model it just gets in the way. See http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised